# Exporting connected graph components *and* their attributes

Tags: python, networkx

I have an undirected graph where each node will have one of three attributes.  Is it possible to export a list of connected component nodes *and* their attributes?

Given this code:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([
    ('Boots',  {"type": "Category"}),
    ('Hats',   {"type": "Category"}),
    ('Coats',  {"type": "Category"}),
    ('Shorts', {"type": "Category"}),

    ('X-Heavy', {"type": "Weight"}),
    ('Heavy',   {"type": "Weight"}),
    ('Medium',  {"type": "Weight"}),
    ('Light',   {"type": "Weight"}),

    ('Red',    {"type": "Color"}),
    ('Orange', {"type": "Color"}),
    ('Yellow', {"type": "Color"}),
    ('Green',  {"type": "Color"}),
    ('Blue',   {"type": "Color"})
])

G.add_edges_from([
    ('Boots', 'Heavy'),
    ('Boots', 'Medium'),
    ('Hats', 'Medium'),
    ('Coats', 'X-Heavy'),
    ('Shorts', 'Light'),
    ('Heavy', 'Red'),
    ('Heavy', 'Orange'),
    ('Medium', 'Yellow'),
    ('Medium', 'Green'),
    ('X-Heavy', 'Yellow'),
    ('Light', 'Blue'),
    ('Boots', 'Red'),
    ('Boots', 'Orange'),
    ('Boots', 'Yellow'),
    ('Hats', 'Green'),
    ('Coats', 'Yellow'),
    ('Shorts', 'Blue')
])

for comps in nx.connected_components(G):
    print(comps)
```

I can get at the (two) graph components:

```
{'Boots', 'Hats', 'Coats', 'X-Heavy', 'Heavy', 'Medium', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green'}
{'Shorts', 'Light', 'Blue'}
```

What I want is to output the same data, but with the node attributes preserved.  I'm imagining something more like this:

```
 {
   "Category": [{'Boots', 'Hats', 'Coats'}],
   "Weight": [{'Heavy', 'Medium', 'X-Heavy'}],
   "Color":[{'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green'}]
 }
 {
   "Category": [{'Shorts'}],
   "Weight": [{'Light'}],
   "Color":[{'Blue'}]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather crude and I'm sure there's a better way but does the job:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d1 = defaultdict(lambda: [])
d2 = defaultdict(lambda: [])
i=0
for comps in nx.connected_components(G):
    #print(comps)
    for c in comps:
        if i == 0:
            d1[G.nodes.data()[c]['type']].append(c)
        else:
            d2[G.nodes.data()[c]['type']].append(c)
            
    i+=1
print(d1.items(),'\n')
print(d2.items())
```

Comment: As an aside: You don't need the `lambda` here: `defaultdict(lambda: [])`. You can just use `defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: yeah I thought I was making it a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach (not that different from the other answer, but a bit cleaner imho): It seems that you want the nodes of each component sorted into `type`-attribute buckets:

```py
nodes_per_type = []
for comp in nx.connected_components(G):
    nodes = {}
    for node in comp:
        nodes.setdefault(G.nodes[node]["type"], set()).add(node)
    nodes_per_type.append(nodes)
```

Result:

```py
[{'Color': {'Orange', 'Red', 'Green', 'Yellow'},
  'Weight': {'Heavy', 'X-Heavy', 'Medium'},
  'Category': {'Boots', 'Coats', 'Hats'}},
 {'Color': {'Blue'}, 'Category': {'Shorts'}, 'Weight': {'Light'}}]
```

I don't understand, though, why you want to put the sets into a list?

If you want to replace the sets with lists, then do:

```py
        nodes.setdefault(G.nodes[node]["type"], []).append(node)
```

instead.